# countif and match using lower version

Tags: excel, countif

What's the formula to use.i need to count the ageing days in column A (>7) that matches a certain text(MISS) in column B.

I'm using 2000 version of xls.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Ageing days'?

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions, you can use CountIfs. In 2000, you need to use SUMPRODUCT. Basically, this produces 2 arrays with TRUE/FALSE values and multiplies them together to get the total number of instances where the same position on both arrays is TRUE.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A > 7)*(B:B ="MISS"))`